# Why I would use TF-IDF after Bag-of-Words (CountVectorizer)?

Tags: nlp, tfidf, bag-of-words

In my recent studies over Machine Learning NLP tasks I found this very nice tutorial teaching how to build your first text classifier:

https://towardsdatascience.com/machine-learning-nlp-text-classification-using-scikit-learn-python-and-nltk-c52b92a7c73a

The point is that I always believed that you have to choose between using Bag-of-Words or WordEmbeddings or TF-IDF, but in this tutorial the author uses Bag-of-Words (CountVectorizer) and then uses TF-IDF over the features generated by Bag-of-Words.

```
text_clf = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer()),
...                      ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
...                      ('clf', MultinomialNB()),
... ])
```

Is that a valid technique? Why would I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This *is* the standard TF-IDF feature extraction: you transform the document counts.  It just looks odd to separate the two steps like this.  `sklearn` provides both [`TfidfTransformer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfTransformer.html) and [`TfidfVectorizer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html); note the documentation of the latter:

> Equivalent to `CountVectorizer` followed by `TfidfTransformer`.

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the answear!